# enabling hover on page load in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am working on a website in which I want to enable hover on page load.

The HTML code which I have used for the tabs are:

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>
```

The CSS code which I have use in order to enable London tab content is:

```
.tab-contents>.active
{
display:block;
}
```

Problem Statement:

I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle so that on page load **London tab is always enable with hover**. The content section is already enabled, I just want to enable the tab now with hover.

Code:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tab-contents>.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div class="tab-contents">
  <div id="London" class="tabcontent active">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *hover*, you mean *selected*.

Then you simply append the corresponded class(`active`).

```
<button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
```

---

Then you want to remove the active when mouse on, simply change this. (only apply `button.active` when mouse is not on `.tab`)

```
.tab:not(:hover) button.active {
   /*^^^^^^^^^^*/
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

---

The full code.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab-bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab:not(:hover) button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tab-contents>.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab-bar">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-contents">
  <div id="London" class="tabcontent active">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `active` tag belongs on the tab, not the button.

Comment: @Barmar the css is `.tab button:hover{...}`, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @apple apple Can you make changes in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpy496v3/embedded/result) In that way it would be easy for me to visualize.

Comment: use Stack Snippet instead of an external link.

Comment: I see, he already has `active` on the default tab, he uses the same class for the corresponding button.

Comment: @apple apple It solves half my problem. On hovering Paris and Tokyo tabs, the london tab is still on hover. I want to work in a way that when page loads the london should have the background color which is present in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wpy496v3/9/embedded/result which is changed by you but on hovering Paris` and Tokyo tabs the london tab hover should not be present

Comment: @appleapple Sorry If I didn't explain my question properly.

Comment: This behaves very weirdly now. When the cursor is over the tab bar, but not over any of the buttons, they all lose their highlights, including the button for the active tab.